# Powershell Export-ScheduledTask returns 0kb files

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've written a script that uses the Powershell command "Export-ScheduledTask" to export all Scheduled Tasks to a folder for copying. The meat of the script is as follows.

```
$SchTasks = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "PROJECT*"
foreach ( $SchTask in $SchTasks ) {
    $SchTask | Export-ScheduledTask | Out-File "C:\Temp\Tasks\$($SchTask.Taskname).xml"
}
```

The script runs without errors. However, one of the dozen tasks is an empty XML file--0 kilobytes. The others are perfect.

I can manually export the one task from Task Scheduler, and it exports without error. Looking at the tasks in Notepad++, the only difference I can see between the manually exported file and a scripted exported file is the second line. In the scripted file it reads:

Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"

In the manual file it reads:

Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"

I've recreated the one task again, which uses the same credentials and most other settings as the others, and it still won't programmatically export properly.

I don't know what's the difference between Task version 1.2 and 1.3, but I don't see why this would fail.

Comment: Can you narrow down the difference between the working and none working ones? Is it a particular setting that causes it?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Both Scheduled Tasks work perfectly. The only difference between the two is which PowerShell script they launch. The difference is only apparent when exporting the tasks to XML.

Comment: If the tasks are completely identically configured for everything, except the file path in the PowerShell command, you don't have any unusual characters in the path name do you? Also can you provide the details of the settings used to see if we can re-produce it (excluding any sensitive info).

Comment: No unusual characters in the filename. Strict alpha-numeric.

Comment: Under "Settings" all I have checked is Allow task to be run on demand, and Stop the task if it runs longer than an hour, and If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop.    Those settings are the same for the Tasks the successfully export with Export-ScheduledTask, and the one that does not.

Comment: I'm just not sure what to make of Task version 1.2 versus 1.3.

Comment: Open a Powershell interactively as the same user running the script. What does following code return: Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Problematic_Task' | Export-ScheduledTask

Comment: Odd. I get...  "Export-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect.    + CategoryInfo : Invalid Argument...[Export-ScheduledTask], CimException

Comment: Doing the same with another Scheduled Task displays the xml data, with Task Version = 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Might be a permission error

Use the following code to display the current permissions of your scheduled tasks to see if there is any difference between them. Replace "YOUR_SUBFOLDER" with the location of the task in the tree.

```
$List = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()
$ScheduledTasks = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\YOUR_SUBFOLDER'
foreach ($ScheduledTask in $ScheduledTasks) {
    $SecurityDescriptorBinary = $ScheduledTask.GetValue('SD')
    $SecurityDescriptorSDDL = ([System.Management.ManagementClass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper').BinarySDToSDDL($SecurityDescriptorBinary).SDDL
    $SecurityDescriptorReadable = $SecurityDescriptorSDDL | ConvertFrom-SddlString

$List.Add([PSCustomObject] @{
    ScheduledTask = $ScheduledTask.PSChildName
    Owner = $SecurityDescriptorReadable.Owner
    Group = $SecurityDescriptorReadable.Group
    ReadableAcl = $SecurityDescriptorReadable.DiscretionaryAcl | Sort-Object | Join-String -Separator "`n"
    SDDL = $SecurityDescriptorSDDL
    })
}
$List | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Thanks, David. But the results are identical down the line of two dozen tasks.